# Auto set password for MySQL root user when install lamp-server via tasksel

Tags: mysql, lamp, execute-command, tasksel

As [guided here](http://www.sudo-juice.com/install-lamp-server-ubuntu/), we can install LAMP via`tasksel` by one single command

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

This includes installing MySQL and will prompt us to enter `root password`.

I need to pass the password from command line so that the installation is fully automated.

How can we get to that?

Comment: You should be able to preseed the debconf database as described here [Is it possible to do an unattended/silent lamp installation?](http://askubuntu.com/a/237720/178692) - see also [Scripted install of MySQL on Ubuntu](http://serverfault.com/a/19399/370258)

Comment: That seems to require us to write LAMP installation script on our own - which I don't think I should follow. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well you're going to have to do *something* beyond simply wishing it so - really it's only two lines (the `debconf-set-selections
` commands for the password question/confirmation). Otherwise, you can use an [expect script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to interact with the installer directly if you prefer - though that's more work IMHO.

Comment: Oh, as it is two extra line, I'll try that again

Comment: echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password PASSWORD | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password PASSWORD | debconf-set-selections

Comment: Is what you mean the two lines above? If it is, then how can we put in the package name with the right version (I don't think 5.1 is alsway true for `tasksel install lamp-server`) http://askubuntu.com/questions/831023/auto-set-password-for-mysql-root-user-when-install-lamp-server-via-tasksel#comment1267189_831023

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm for me on plain Ubuntu16 server:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='xxxxx';
echo debconf mysql-server/root_password password $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD | sudo debconf-set-selections;
echo debconf mysql-server/root_password_again password $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD | sudo debconf-set-selections;
sudo apt-get -y install lamp-server^;
```